# Fail to upload to Google Drive on multiple Airflow GCP connection scope

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, airflow, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I'm building a DAG that would upload files to Google Drive at the end, utilizing Airflow's `GoogleDriveHook`. As this is executed using a service account, I use my email as the `delegate_to` parameter, and enabled domain-wide delegation beforehand. Scope for the email is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`.

DAG would run just fine if the connection's scope is just that, however, since I use the same Airflow connection for other DAGs that utilizes other GCP services, I would have to use multiple scopes for that aforementioned connection.

For some reason, it would fail during upload on multiple scopes, spewing out:

```
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.', '{\n  "error": "unauthorized_client",\n  "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested."\n}')
```

Though having multiple Airflow connections is not much of a deal-breaker, I guess at this point I'm just curious to why this happens (Airflow 1.10.9)?

Comment: Do the credentials you are using contain the updated scopes? @GregoriusAriaNeruda

Comment: @ale13 I'm not quite sure what you mean by "credentials contains the updated scopes". Should the service account JSON file have the updated scope in it? If you were referring to `google.auth.credentials.Credentials`, AFAIK `GoogleDriveHook` should do the work already, and as I've said, uploading files succeeds if the scope in the Airflow connection is **only**  `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`. Any addition to that it would just fail.

Answer (score 0):

> I use my email as the delegate_to parameter

1. Did you use a gsuite domain email?
2. Did you set up domain wide delegation in GSuite?

Delegate to only works with Gsuite domain emails.

If you want the service account to be able to access you personal non g suite google account. Then you will need to share a directory on your persona drive account and grant the service account access to that directory like you would any other user by sharing the directory with it.

Once files are uploaded they will be owned by the service account you will then need to ensure to insert permissions for that file so that your personal account will then have access to the files.

Comment: 1. Yes
2. Yes

The problem I'm facing is that it fails to upload whenever I have multiple scope in my Airflow connection.